# import python packages from a zip file in c/c++ standalone application

Tags: c++, python, c, boost-python

am using a python scripts in c/c++ program and i want to import python packages from a zip file as in Sublime Text, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html).

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, 'example.zip')  # Add .zip file to front of path
>>> import foobar
```